# Prolog backtracking position

Tags: prolog, backtracking

Given the following:

```
R(p):-
    a(p),
    b(p),
    c(p).
```

When `c` fails, it will backtrack to `b` and unbind `b`. However, I want it to backtrack from `a` and unbind `b` as well as `a` instead. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may use an [if->then](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(-%3E)/2) construct to commit the changes from the goal you do not want to backtrack (put them on the left hand side of `->/2`).

For example if you want to skip backtracking for the `b/1` goal you may do this:

```
r(P):-
  a(P),
  ( 
     b(P) 
  -> c(P)
  ).
```

with these test facts:

```
a([a1|_]).
a([a2|_]).

b([_,b1|_]).
b([_,b2|_]).

c([_,_,c1]).
c([_,_,c2]).
```

and this sample query:

```
?- r(P).
P = [a1, b1, c1] ;
P = [a1, b1, c2] ;
P = [a2, b1, c1] ;
P = [a2, b1, c2].
```